# AutoComplete not filtering the list items Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want the `county` field to have an auto-complete option, because the items in list are so much that user sometime gets offended by scrolling & scrolling.
there are two problems with the code currently.

First is that the input box appears fine, but whatever I type it doesn't filters from the list

Second is that my `county` object has two properties `countyId` and `countyName` when I select the county from list it shows the `countyId` not the name, because It is bind with Id. How do I change it so that it shows the name and still bound with Id as I need the id to send to server.

here is my html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="50" class="pr-4">
    <!-- <mat-label>County</mat-label> -->
    <input type="text" placeholder="select county" name="" matInput [formControl]="countyId" [matAutocomplete]="auto">

    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let county of counties" [value]="county.countyId">
            {{county.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>

    <!-- <mat-select formControlName="countyId">
        <mat-option *ngFor='let county of counties' [value]="county.countyId">
            {{county.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select> -->

</mat-form-field>
```

and here is my `ts` file code

```
  ref: ComponentRef<any>;
  newCustomerForm: FormGroup;
  counties; // list of counties
  subCounties; 
  filteredCounties: Observable<string[]>;

this.newCustomerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
          nationalId: ['', Validators.required],
          name: ['', Validators.required],
          gender: ['', Validators.required],
          phone1: [''],
          phone2: [''],
          countyId: ['', Validators.required],
          subCountyId: ['', Validators.required],
          bishopName: ['', Validators.required],
          bishopPhone: ['', Validators.required],
          address: ['', Validators.required],
          additionalInfo: [''],
          input1: [''],
          input2: [''],
          defaultingRecord: [''],
        });

ngOnInit() {
    // Getting the list of counties
    this.countyService.getCounties().subscribe((response) => {
      this.counties = response;
      this.filteredCounties = this.newCustomerForm.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
    });
    // Getting a list of sub-counties
    this.subCountyService.getSubCounties().subscribe((response) => {
      this.subCounties = response;
    });
  }
  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.counties.filter(county=> county.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
```

Picture for better understanding
[image: Picture for better understanding]

Comment: please provide a stackblitz demo if the posted answer doesn't helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your object in your template not single properties:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="50" class="pr-4">
    <input type="text" placeholder="select county" name="country" matInput [formControl]="country" [matAutocomplete]="auto">

    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let countryof countries" [value]="country">
            {{country.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>

</mat-form-field>
```

and add in your component function displayFn() as I did here:

```
displayFn(country?: Country): string | undefined {
    return country? country.name : undefined;
  }
```

Comment: and how to deal with `filter` function that is in my `ts` file, will it be required or not by using your method ?

Comment: Yes, situation with that logic will not be changed. But I think you should change your indexOf(filterValue) === 0  to includes(filterValue).

Comment: Although your code has some bugs but I got an idea how to deal with it
Thanks